# Ho to make any ViewController in UITabBar initial?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tabBar with 3 vc's, and a first vc is the one which is being shown(FavoritesNC)

```
tabbar.viewControllers = [FavoritesNC(), NewsFeedNC(), MediaSourcesNC()]
```

I want to keep the order of tabBar items, but to make NewsFeed to be initial(the first one being shown, when I open an app). Is there a way?

Comment: try tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 in tabbarViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [selectedIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621171-selectedindex):

> Setting this property changes the selected view controller to the one
>   at the designated index in the viewControllers array.

```swift
tabbar.viewControllers = [FavoritesNC(), NewsFeedNC(), MediaSourcesNC()]
tabbar.selectedIndex = 1
```